# How this dict is constructed?

Tags: python

I can't understand how this dictionary is constructed:

```
chars="0123456789+ "
self.char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(self.chars))
```

I found this code in an example of [keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/61052bc1f1c141c5dba9f83a4af14322ec4e6d7c/examples/addition_rnn.py#L50).

Can someone can explain what is happening?

Edit:
Specifically I don't understand what kind of data structure is passed to dict().
How the variable i is generated?
I'm asking a detailed explanation of the code

Comment: `self.chars` and `self.char_indices` are defined in the `CharacterTable` class. [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a built-in function.

Comment: Which part do you specifically not understand?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? Also I assume that you mean `self.chars="0123456789+ "`. Otherwise this example doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It makes a dictionary where the keys are the characters from the string, and the values are the character's position in the string.

Answer (score 1):

the following code is equivalent :

```
self.char_indices = {}
for index, char in enumerate(self.chars):
    self.char_indices[char] = index
```

using self.char_indices dict you can find in O(1) time complexity where a specific character is in self.chars (characters that can appear in the input)

Answer (score 0):

`dict` accepts a list of key, value pairs; the generator expression provides one by producing a tuple of each pair in the enumeration.

Comment: Isn't it a generator expression, not a list comprehension?

Comment: @khelwood Thanks - the correct term escaped me. Updated.

Comment: Also the generator expression does not provide a **list**, as your answer says.